# How can I get pdf file content from supabase storage bucket using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sveltekit, supabase-database

I have a svelte project which shows the information from supabase.
What I need is that get the binary data of pdf file which is uploaded to supabase storage and then extract text from it.

Currently I get only metadata like this:

`bucket_id: "..." created_at: "2022-07-05T09:40:30.186775+00:00" id: "9ce8d403-802a-4cd3-9e78-dcc8ad0a5091" last_accessed_at: "2022-07-05T09:40:30.186775+00:00" metadata: {size: 91400, mimetype: "application/pdf", cacheControl: "max-age=3600"} cacheControl: "max-age=3600" mimetype: "application/pdf" size: 91400 name: "ATL LT 000002 - 22_SCP2022285639_CivilCaseJacket.pdf" owner: null path_tokens: ["ATL LT 000002 - 22_SCP2022285639_CivilCaseJacket.pdf"] updated_at: "2022-07-05T09:40:30.368694+00:00"`

I would be really appreciated if anyone help me to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your code? E.g. how are you accessing the data? Are you using https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-download ?